# AS3/Flex 4: Easing via AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flex4

This is probably something simple but I'm scratching my head over easing with the `Animate` class in Flex 4.

Basically I'm just trying to set easing via:

```
anim.easer = spark.effects.easing.EaseInOutBase(EasingFraction.IN_OUT);
```

however, it complains, saying

```
Type Coercion failed: cannot convert 0.5 to spark.effects.easing.EaseInOutBase.
```

Which would be fine, except... the constructor argument is a `Number`, not an instance of `EaseInOutBase`.  Am I missing something?  All of Google's results suggest that this should be defined via MXML, but I just feel... dirty doing it - rather, defining something that is purely programmatic with markup.  I know that's half the nature of Flex, but still, I like to keep most of my logic/configuration in AS3.

If there's a better way to animate with easing than using `Animate` with its `easer` property (eg, if this isn't the right way), feel free to suggest an alternative - still a bit new to Flex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  You are certainly missing something... :)  You are missing the `new` keyword.

Your code is trying to cast `EasingFraction.IN_OUT` to the type `EaseInOutBase`... which is why you get that seemingly (but completely appropriate) error.

Instead:

```
anim.easer = new spark.effects.easing.EaseInOutBase(EasingFraction.IN_OUT);
```

:)

Comment: Indeed I am. :) That'll teach me to code when exhausted. Thank you!